Any library that is supported on Arm64 based server for generating a pdf
Our application has an invoice generation functionality with a download option. When downloading a pdf we need to generate it based on the HTML view. It is an ARM64 based server so any library which uses Chrome is not supported. We need to generate it from the server side because we attach the pdf when the invoice is shared via email.
Any suggestions?
